# Convert class route data code mvc to ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

I have a code for sub domain that I want to convert ASP.NET Core 3.1.
Can you explain to me exactly what you did and how you converted the code?

This code is used for user subdomains without creating it on the host
I did a lot of tests, but I couldn't reach the result, that's why I searched and found this code, and it works correctly and is solved. I want to convert it.

Class route dta

```
public class SubdomainRoute : RouteBase
{
    private readonly string _subDomain;
    private readonly RouteValueDictionary _routeData;

    public SubdomainRoute(string subDomain, object routeData) :
            this(subDomain, new RouteValueDictionary(routeData))
    { }

    public SubdomainRoute(string subDomain, RouteValueDictionary routeData)
    {
        _subDomain = subDomain;
        _routeData = routeData;
    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var url = httpContext.Request.Headers["HOST"];

        var index = url.IndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal);

        if (index < 0) 
            return null;

        var firstDomain = url.Split('.')[0];

        if ((firstDomain.Equals("www") || firstDomain.Equals("localhost"))
            && !firstDomain.Equals(_subDomain))
            return null;

        var handler = new MvcRouteHandler();
        var result = new RouteData { RouteHandler = handler };

        foreach (var route in _routeData)
        {
            result.Values.Add(route.Key, route.Value);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Next code map route:

```
routes.Add(new SubdomainRoute("m",
                              new 
                              { 
                                  controller = "M", 
                                  action = "Index", 
                                  id = UrlParameter.Optional 
                              }));
routes.MapRoute(name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
               );
```

Thank you for converting the code and sending it to me

Comment: what is the question?  This reads like an e-mail exchange.  (and has solution which appears to be to set routing accordingly in asp.net...)

Comment: I want to convert the above codes to asp .net core 3.1 For the subdomain according to url

Comment: Is your posted the ASP.NET code?